# Python - Abrir múltiplos arquivos em um For

Tags: python, arquivo

Alguém, por favor, poderia me ajudar explicando porque não consigo adicionar os textos de cada arquivo em cada posição da minha lista?

```
''' Funções para o processamento dos textos (cartas) para base de aprendizagem'''

PATH_LETTERS = 'resources/letters/'
MODE_OPEN = 'r'
NAME_DEFAULT_FILES = 'carta_{}'
EXENSION_LETTERS = '.txt'
PATH_FULL_LETTERS = PATH_LETTERS + NAME_DEFAULT_FILES + EXENSION_LETTERS


def get_text(size_letters=18):

    letters = []

    try:
        for i in range(1, (size_letters+1)):

            text = ''

            letter = open(PATH_FULL_LETTERS.format(i), MODE_OPEN)

            for line in letter.readlines():

                text += line

            letter.close()
            letters.append(text)
        return letters

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Error opening letter file')
```

Sempre que executo esse código os textos de todos os arquivos de texto ficam na mesma posição na lista, por quê?

Sendo que tenho 18 arquivos, o for mais externo serve pra mim passar e ler todos eles.

Basicamente, eu tenho 18 arquivos de textos e quero ler cada um, e adicionar o conteúdo de arquivo em cada posição da lista, então.... ao meu ver, o código acima deveria funcionar, no entanto quanto imprimo no terminal a lista, o conteúdo de todos os arquivos aparece em uma única posição. Então, poderiam me ajudar?

Código que eu exibo a saída:

```
import classifier as clr
import text_processor

if __name__ == '__main__':

    classifier = clr.Classifier()

    phrase = text_processor.get_text()

    print(phrase)
```

Saída no terminal com somente 2 arquivos para não ficar muito grande:

```
['São Paulo 18 de julho de 1988\nEdu estou deixando esta carta para mostrar a\nvocê o que sinto e o que estou sentindo.\nEdu são 2:15 hs da madrugada não consegui\ndormir um minuto se quer esta tudo doendo\ndentro de mim só em pensar que ti perdi de\nverdade.\nDu porque você fingiu, porque você mentiu\npara mim este tempo todo. Du não estou\naguentando mais, está sendo duro resistir\nesta dor tão grande que estou sentindo\ndentro de mim e por viver assim preferi\nmorrer.\nEdu quando lembrar-se de mim lembre-se que\nti amei e amei de verdade\n', 'Carlos\nEu precisava tanto falar contigo, pena, você\nnão deixou. Vou morrer te amando. Eu te\namo loucamente. Tudo o que fiz de errado, foi\numa necessidade de estar com você outra\nvez.\nVocê não quiz me ouvir. Agora será impossível\nme ouvir outra vez. Eu te amo. Se tomei esta\niniciativa foi simplesmente pelo fato de saber\nque nunca mais o teria de volta.\nPor mim, peça desculpas à minha mãe. Diga a\nela que eu a amo muito também porém não\nencontrei mais nenhuma existência para mim.\nEu te amo, tudo o que fiz foi porque o amava\ndemais. Tentei explicar isto à minha mãe: não\nse preocupe, será impossível te ligar outra\nvez.\n\nEu, Márcia, dou meus olhos, meus cabelos e\nmeu sangue a quem\nprecisar.\nJuro estar dizendo a verdade, perante todos e\na Deus.\n\nSem ele não viver mais.\n']
```

Comment: Não dá pra entender essa pergunta. O que você quer fazer? O seu código faz exatamente o que você manda: abre todos os arquivos, um depois do outro, e coloca o texto de todos em uma lista final.

Comment: Quem deu "upvote" nessa pergunta, poderia explicar a mesma melhor?

Comment: Expliquei melhor a pergunta.

Comment: @NayronMorais eu repliquei seu código e não teve o comportamento que você descreveu. Cada arquivo ficou em uma posição da lista: https://repl.it/NbdC/0. Não é esse o resultado esperado? Como você está exibindo a lista no terminal?

Comment: Da mesma forma que sua replicação! E sim,o resultado era este mesmo. Vou editar a pergunta exibindo uma imagem com a saída do terminal.

Comment: esse código está dando mais voltas do que deveria, mas está "correto". O erro, se houver, é no ponto em que você pega o valor de retorno da função e o imprime. Ou talvez com os seus arquivos.

Comment: Como assim mais voltas do que deveria?

Comment: Adicionei mais informações na pergunta!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A única diferença é que a minha versão do Python é 3.5.

Comment: É necessário que a ordem das cartas seja mantida na lista final?

Comment: Não precisa.... mas fui atrás do que @jsbueno disse, modifiquei as quebra de linha  dos arquivos aqui e aparentemente deu certo... só achei estranho isso... alguém saberia explicar?

Comment: coloquem a resposta que dou os votos, resolvi aqui!

Comment: @NayronMorais que modificações fez?

Comment: Apenas tirei as quebra de linha dos arquivos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solução com `pathlib.Path`

Uma forma simples de se fazer o desejado é utilizando a biblioteca [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text), disponível a partir da versão 3.4 do Python, através da classe `Path`.

Passando como parâmetro do construtor um caminho, você terá um objeto que representa o diretório:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('resources/letters/')
```

Um dos métodos dessa classe é o `glob`, que pode buscar por arquivos que casam com um determinado nome:

```
letters_files = path.glob('carta_*.txt')
```

Assim, você pode percorrer este iterável e utilizar o método `read_text` para obter o conteúdo de cada arquivo:

```
letters = [letter.read_text() for letter in letters_files]
```

Ficando:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('resources/letters/')
letters_files = path.glob('carta_*.txt')
letters = [letter.read_text() for letter in letters_files]

print(letters)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nbga/0)</sup>

Porém, desta forma, não há garantias da ordem do resultado. Isto é, o conteúdo da `carta_2.txt` pode vir antes de `carta_1.txt`. Se a ordem for necessária, você pode ordenar a lista pelo nome do arquivo antes de ler os respectivos conteúdos:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('resources/letters/')
letters_files = path.glob('carta_*.txt')
letters = [letter.read_text() for letter in sorted(letters_files)]

print(letters)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NbhG/0)</sup>

Ainda, este código pode ser escrito em apenas uma linha:

```
letters = [letter.read_text() for letter in Path('resources/letters/').glob('carta_*.txt')]
```

Produzindo o mesmo resultado.

## Solução seguindo a lógica da pergunta

Simplificando o código apresentado na pergunta, seria possível fazer algo como:

```
PATH_LETTERS = 'resources/letters/'
MODE_OPEN = 'r'
NAME_DEFAULT_FILES = 'carta_{}'
EXENSION_LETTERS = '.txt'
PATH_FULL_LETTERS = PATH_LETTERS + NAME_DEFAULT_FILES + EXENSION_LETTERS


def get_text(size_letters=18):

    letters = []

    for i in range(size_letters):
        try:
            with open(PATH_FULL_LETTERS.format(i+1), MODE_OPEN) as letter:
                letters.append(letter.read())
        except OSError:
            print("Arquivo %s não encontrado" % PATH_FULL_LETTERS.format(i+1))

    return letters

print(get_text())
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Nbkc/0)</sup>

Comment: Phyton é vida ♥ !

Comment: @MagicHat *Phyton*? hehe

Comment: É mano, num sabia? -> https://ideone.com/2QACcB