# Escrever arquivo em JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Tenho uma série de arquivos no formato JSON, para trabalhar melhor organizo todos eles em um arquivo único utilizando o seguinte método:

```
import json 

filename = "dados_geral.json"

for mensagens in range(1,6):
    arq='data_gephi_%d.json' % (mensagens)

    with open(arq,'r') as f:
       for linha in f:
           tweet = json.dumps(linha)
           filename.write(tweet)
filename.close()
```

Porém, ao tentar separar os dados que um juntei e reescrevê-los como estavam antes usando

```
import json 


with open('dados_juntos.json','r') as f: 
    c=0
    for linha in f: 
        c+=1
        file = 'dados_%d.json'%(c)
        arq = open(file,'wb')
        tweet = json.loads(linha)# ->Transforma uma string JSON em objeto.
        #tweet = json.dumps(linha)#-> Transforma um objeto em string JSON.
        #print(type(tweet))
        arq.write(tweet)
    arq.close()
```

Quando utilizo o .dumps ele escreve o arquivo como str e perco o acesso a hierarquia do arquivo e ao tentar e utilizando o .loads ocorre o erro

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

Então, como posso escrever um arquivo unindo todos os meus dados e depois separando sem perder acesso a informação?

Comment: Isso não parece fazer sentido. Por quê você precisa salvar todos os arquivos em um só e depois separá-los? Como você saberá quando começa e termina o conteúdo de um determinado arquivo dentro do `dados_juntos.json`? Porque a lógica que você colocou na pergunta *salvaria* cada linha em um arquivo diferente e isso parece estar longe do que deseja fazer.

Comment: É que eu tenho uma série de tweets salvos separadamente em arquivos JSON. Então ao invés de ter 10k de arquivos de tweets gostaria de ter apenas 1 com todos eles, nesse formato, um por linha.                                   Mas como vc pode ver ao escrever todos em um único arquivo ele deixa de ser um arquivo do tipo dic e passa a ser str e isso não é interessante para mim, já que ainda quero ter aceso a hierarquia dos dados.  Por isso surgiu a duvida de como escrever o arquivo mantendo o acesso possível.

Comment: O problema é semelhante a [este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251807/5878), dê uma lida na solução. Perceba que se vcê quer apenas transcrever o conteúdo de um arquivo para outro, você não precisa utilizar o módulo `json`; basta ler e escrever o conteúdo.

Comment: O que quero alcançar é: tenho dois arquivos JSON, quero escrever um arquivo geral contendo estes dois nele para que depois eu posso separar e poder avaliá-los separadamente. Mas ao escrever esse arquivo geral os dados nele deixam de ser um dicionários e se tornam strings. Acredito que transcrever não ajudaria, mas irei olhar sim, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Os arquivos de origem tem linhas quebradas então talvez vc deveria usar o código abaixo (como não tinha os arquivos não testei então pode ter algum erro)...

```
import json 

filename = "dados_geral.json"

for mensagens in range(1,6):
    arq='data_gephi_%d.json' % (mensagens)

    with open(arq,'r') as f:
       conteudo = f.readlines()
       tweet = json.dumps(comteudo)
       filename.write(tweet)
       filename.write("# /* SEPARADOR */")
filename.close()
```

Para ler o arquivo algo assim:

import json

```
with open('dados_juntos.json','r') as f: 
    c=0
    msg=''
    for linha in f: 
        if not linha.startswith('# /* SEPARADOR */'):
            msg += linha
        else:
            c+=1
            file = 'dados_%d.json'%(c)
            arq = open(file,'wb')
            arq.write(msg)
            arq.close()
```

Comment: O arquivo de saida no primeiro código deve ser aberto...