# Verificar tamanho de cada arquivo em uma pasta em Python com 'os'

Tags: python

Estou com certa dificuldade para descobrir o tamanho de cada arquivo (em KB) em uma certa pasta.
Inicialmente listei todos os arquivos com o 'os.listdir' e acredito que tenha algo haver com o 'os.stat' para descobrir o tamanho de cada arquivo listado.

```
import os
lista = os.PathLike('c:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Python para redes\\TP1')
tamanho = os.stat(lista)
print(tamanho.st_size)
```

Comment: **Thiago**, poderia **por favor** [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/323786/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código que você já fez ou um [mcve] ?

Comment: import os
lista = os.PathLike('c:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Python para redes\\TP1')
tamanho = os.stat(lista)
print(tamanho.st_size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu deves verificar qual o tamanho ficheiro a ficheiro e não de uma lista de ficheiros.

Para verificares o tamanho de cada arquivo em um diretório podes usar [`getsize`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize), que basicamente retorna `os.stat(ficheiro).st_size`, e é em `bytes`, logo vamos ter de converter:

```
import os

dir_path = '/caminho/para/ficheiros/'
files = os.listdir(dir_path)
for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(dir_path,f)
    f_size = os.path.getsize(f_path)
    f_size_kb = f_size/1024 # obter resultado em kB
    print(f_path, f_size_kb)
```

Se quiseres ignorar os diretórios podes ([`isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)):

```
import os

dir_path = '/caminho/para/ficheiros/'
files = os.listdir(dir_path)
for f in files:
    f_path = os.path.join(dir_path,f)
    if(os.path.isfile(f_path)): # verificar se e ficheiro
        f_size = os.path.getsize(f_path)
        f_size_kb = f_size/1024 # obter resultado em kB
        print(f_path, f_size_kb)
```

Alternativa com [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.walk), desta a maneira consegues facilmente verificar todos os ficheiros de todos os diretórios recursivamente a partir de um diretório pai:

```
import os

dir_path = '/caminho/para/ficheiros/'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dir_path): # obtendo caminho atual, diretorios e ficheiros respetivamente
    for f in filenames: # percorrer ficheiros em cada diretorio (dirpath)
        f_path = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        f_size = os.path.getsize(f_path)
        f_size_kb = f_size/1024 # obter resultado em kB
        print(f_path, f_size_kb)
```

**Nota:** estou a dividir por `1024` para obter o tamanho em kB apesar de muitos sistemas dividirem  por `1000`, suponho que seja uma escolha tua, [ler mais](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/4425/should-i-teach-that-1-kb-1024-bytes-or-1000-bytes)

[Questão semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251807/python-abrir-m%C3%BAltiplos-arquivos-em-um-for?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Esse código pega a soma de todos os tamanhos de todos os arquivos em uma pasta e todas as suas subpastas (em bytes, se quiser kb é só dividir por 1024 depois).

O legal é que ele é super compacto e ainda assim legível:

```
import os

dir_path = r'c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Python para redes\TP1'
total = sum(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, f)) 
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path) for f in files)
```